# Where do I learn to manage a Mac OS Server network?

Tags: osx-server

I inherited a network with 2 Mac OS Servers and 20+ Macbook Pros. My background is all Windows server so I get the concept of Open Directory, Server Admin, and Workgroup Manager, but the nuts and bolts are more difficult to pick up.

Can someone recommend a starting point to learn all of this? So much of the resources I found out there are for home users and not necessarily for a work environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Ifskills**](http://www.ifskills.com/) has a great tutorial of Mac OS X Server. I'm still going through it myself. It is massively helpful.

Comment: Also @zippy, feel free to ask any of those questions on AskDifferent. Those of us that know would be happy to answer as best we can.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for...sorry if my question wasn't clear enough for everyone else's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has a certification program analogous to Microsoft's MCSE (Microsoft Certified Systems Engineer) certification. They have [classroom training at authorized training centers](http://training.apple.com/locations), but they are offered in far fewer cities and less often than those for Microsoft or Cisco. If your employer is willing to pay for it, it would be a good idea to pursue this.

I hold three Apple certifications (see [my Ask Different profile](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9290/wheat-williams) here on this site) although none of mine are in network administration.

You might want to pursue the [Apple Certified Technical Coordinater](http://training.apple.com/certification/macosx) certification. If not, at least look at the training materials and third-party books that cover preparation for the Apple OS X Server Essentials 10.7 Exam (9L0-515), or the previous exam for 10.6, which is still available.

Look at [Apple's Training and Certification](http://training.apple.com/certification) web site to learn about their program.

In the meantime, I would steer you to the [Apple-authorized training books from Peachpit Press](http://www.peachpit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0321775082).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a learning place you can check:

http://www.certifiedtraining.com/coursedesc.php?id=101
http://www.learningtree.com/search/search.aspx?Submit.x=0&Submit.y=0&Submit=Submit&q=Mac
http://training.apple.com/classes
http://www.lynda.com/Mac-OS-X-10-7-tutorials/Mac-OS-X-Lion-Essential-Training/85081-2.html

If looking to learn on your own at your own pace... there are great resources/books out there. A few listed below:

Mac OS X Lion Server For Dummies (For Dummies (Computer/Tech))
Mac OS X Lion Bible
Apple Pro Training Series: OS X Lion Support Essentials: Supporting and Troubleshooting OS X Lion